# Are there languages that distinguish "us-not-you" from "us-including-you"?

Tags: pronouns

In the languages I’m familiar with, the first-person plural pronouns (e.g., “us”, “we”, “ours”) apply regardless of whether the listener is included in the group. It seems to me that this often produces ambiguity. For example, I recently wanted to say:

> Could **we** meet before **our** committee meeting next week?

but, since “we” would mean “you and I" while “our” would mean “belonging to other people and me”, this construction would have been confusing. The best I could do with English pronouns was:

> Could **you and I** meet before **my** committee meeting next week?

which conveys the needed distinction but is unparsimonious and requires substituting a singular pronoun ("my") where I wanted a plural one ("us-not-you").

**Are there languages that draw this distinction?**